# cannot access phpmyadmin

Tags: phpmyadmin

I get this error everytime I try to access phpmyadmin. 
http://i49.tinypic.com/ot1478.jpg

I cant access it because I've put a password on the root user. How do I get to have a login form in phpmyadmin so that I could at least try to authenticate that I'm the root user.
Because in its current state, it wouldnt even bother to authenticate who is the user by at least having a login form.
How do I get to have a login form in phpmyadmin. I'm just a beginner and I don't have time to read on documentations that can take days to read. Like this one: http://www.phpmyadmin.net/documentation/Documentation.html#config

Please help. Im stuck in this problem I couldnt get any solutions from google or in any other place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm just a beginner and I don't have time to read on documentations that can take days to read.

That's a very, very bad way to start fiddling with phpMyAdmin. :) (or any other security sensitive software, for that matter.)

There's a [**Quick Install**](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/documentation/Documentation.html#setup) chapter. Have you tried starting the setup script? It makes installation *very* easy. You just need to keep in mind that it won't install the configuration file it creates - you need to put that into the phpMyAdmin directory manually using your FTP program.

Answer (score 0):

Taken from [here...](http://www.theadminzone.com/forums/showthread.php?t=16357)

You need to change the values for the $cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] and $cfg['Servers'][$i]['passwd'] in phpMyAdmin's config file. Before you do that though, look at the value for $cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type']. If it's "config", then go ahead and change the username and password to whatever you want. If it's "cookie" or "http", then you need to create a new MySQL user account before you change those values.